# How do I replace lookup_widget in Glade3/GTK3 code?

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I have recently resurrected a project from a decade ago (https://github.com/clancyj4/z80sim) and I'm running into problems that are related to the transition from glade 2 to 3.

One problem is that I use a function lookup_widget which is defined in support.c by glade 2, but is not defined in glade 3.  And I don't know how to replace it.

An example of how I use it is:

```
void init_Code(GtkWidget *Main)
{
  GtkWidget *widget;
  PangoFontDescription *codefont;

  codetext = lookup_widget(Main, "Code_Text");
  code_textbuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(codetext));
```

I have looked the problem up, of course, but I don't understand the answer which was:

```
The preferred solution is to pass a pointer to your ENTRY as the user data pointer when you connect the signal, or, if you're using gtk_builder_connect_signals(), store a pointer to ENTRY in your class and pass the class as the user data pointer.
```

which was referring to:

```
on_BT_OK_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    //The line directly below is the one I get an error on
    GtkWidget *entry = lookup_widget( GTK_WIDGET(button), "ENTRY" );
```

Any clarification would be most helpful.

**EDIT:**
I'm pretty sure that the signals are all connected because I use this:

```
  builder = gtk_builder_new();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "z80em2.glade", NULL);

  window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Main"));
  gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
```

As I understand it `codetext = lookup_widget(Main, "Code_Text")`  returns a pointer to the GtkWidget referred to as Code_Text under the Main widget and I don't see how to do that in GTK3.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Glade, but if you have "manual" code that connects the signal handler, you should pass a pointer to that other widget in that call. That will then be stored inside GTK+, and passed as the `user_pointer` argument to the event handler.

So it would become just:

```
on_BT_OK_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    // This assumes the entry was passed to g_signal_connect() as 'data'
    GtkWidget *entry = GTK_WIDGET(user_data);
```

See [`g_signal_connect()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect).

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to rewrite this codebase heavily anyway, you may find it helpful to reorganize the widgets into composite widget templates, which Glade 3 supports, and use [`gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-class-bind-template-child) to make all the widgets that you would have otherwise looked up with `lookup_widget()` into members of your widget class. But it's not a good short-term fix, because it would involve a lot of refactoring.